Changing the "Dear" in the Email Greeting token
I want to change the formal text "Dear" to a Maori greeting term - "Kia ora" in the standard Email Greeting token availble in CiviMail.

These docs tell you where to go to change the format, and then how to update it for existing contacts.
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_update_greeting

Thanks for the link to Scheduled Job - Update Greetings and Addressees. All fixed now –
